# Paypal Integration in React JS

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I am trying to integrate paypal payment into my e-commerce app. So far, the payment works only with a predefined amount in the createOrder function. I have a value(passed as prop) that I would want to set to be the payment amount but I am failing to figure this out.

Below is my code

```
     function paymentForm({item}) {

    
    const createOrder = (data, actions) =>{
        return actions.order.create({
           purchase_units: [
             {
                amount: {
                   value: "1",
                },
             },
          ], 
      });
    };
    
    
    
    return (
    <>
        {/*item.totalPrice: is the value I want to set the payment amount to(passed as prop) */}

        <p> Subtotal: {item.totalPrice} </p>
    
         <PayPalButton className="paypal"
           createOrder={(data, actions) => createOrder(data, actions)}
           onApprove={(data, actions) => onApprove(data, actions)}
          />
    
    </>
   

  )

    }
```

What I did was to directly set value to {item.totalPrice} but this does not work.

Thanks for helping in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example...

```
() => {
    const [amount, setAmount] = useState(2);
    const [orderID, setOrderID] = useState(false);

    function createOrder(data, actions) {
        return actions.order
            .create({
                purchase_units: [
                    {
                        amount: {
                            value: amount,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            })
            .then((orderID) => {
                setOrderID(orderID);
                return orderID;
            });
    }

    function onChange({ target: { value } }) {
        setAmount(value);
        setOrderID(false);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <label htmlor="amount">Order Amount: </label>
            <select onChange={onChange} name="amount" id="amount">
                <option value="2">$2.00</option>
                <option value="4">$4.00</option>
                <option value="6">$6.00</option>
            </select>
            <p>Order ID: {orderID ? orderID : "unknown"}</p>

            <PayPalButtons createOrder={createOrder} forceReRender={[amount]} />
        </>
    );
}
```

Source: https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--dynamic-amount

Comment: Thanks so much for the link! Is there a way to set an option value to a prop instead of a string? e.g instead of having;
<option value="2">
we have <option value={this.prop.price}>

Comment: Of course there's a way; I'd read up on JSX syntax for that, and do a couple google searches if it's not clear